# Combining function output into data frame with different column names

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to get a single data frame (or a tibble) with distinct column names from this function. This code prints three separate chunks with the same Date and same column names. Column values are however different.

```
hello <- function(x){
  fx <- Quandl(x)

  fx <- fx %>%
    select(Date, Open, Close) %>%
    mutate(new_col = `Open` - `Close`) %>%
    select(Date, new_col)
  print(kable(head(fx), format = "rst"))
}

lapply(c(EUR, USD, RUB), fx)
```

I am doing it the long way via replicating the code for every input (EUR, USD, RUB). Then merging them with the function below, then converting to a tibble to get rid of the observation numbers on the left before printing via kable.

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), list(EUR, USD, RUB))
```

Just want to see how it is possible to do easier with one function.

Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**

Thank you for the answers and suggestions on improving the question!

So the reproducible code looks like this:

```
Wheat<-"CFTC/001602_FO_ALL"
Corn<-"CFTC/002602_F_ALL"
Beans<-"CFTC/005602_F_ALL"

funds<-function(x){

  cftc<-Quandl(x)

cftc<-cftc%>%
  select(Date,`Money Manager Longs`,`Money Manager Shorts`)%>%
  mutate(Funds_Net = `Money Manager Longs`-`Money Manager Shorts`)%>%
  select(Date,Funds_Net)
print(kable(head(cftc),format = "rst"))
}

lapply(c(Wheat,Corn,Beans),funds)
```

The output I have is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGIBF.png)

What I want as output is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqcOO.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()`.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are asking without knowing what the data look like or what the Quandl() function does.